# How to pass data from one function to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to read the data using the getExcel function and then pass it to the stats function that resturds df.describe (pandas.describe) to show the descriptive statistics (mean, max, min etc) of the data loaded. How do I do this?

```py
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    import pandas as pd
    
    def getExcel ():
        global df
        import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        data = pd.read_csv (import_file_path).iloc[:,1:]  
        df = data.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).ffill().bfill() 
    
    def stats(getExcel): 
        return df.describe()
```

Comment: To the...? Please be specific on what you're trying to achieve, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I wants to be able to read the data using the getExcel function and then pass it to the stats function that resturds df.describe (pandas.describe) to show the descriptive statistics (mean, max, min etc) of the data loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you don't mean the the obvious solution of simply having one function call the other. You can make them methods of the same class, and have the data the second one needs be part of the instance data...in which case it should likely be  initialized upon construction.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        df = getExcel()

    def getExcel(self):
        import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        data = pd.read_csv (import_file_path).iloc[:,1:]  
        self.df = data.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).ffill().bfill()
        return self.df 

    def stats(self): 
        return self.df.describe()
```

Answer (score 0):

`getExcel` needs to return the data. You can then pass that data into `stats`:

```
def getExcel():
    ...
    return df

def stats(df): 
    return df.describe()

df = getExcel()
result = stats(df)
```